# execle returns a bad adress when called in a loop

Tags: c, linux

For a project, I have to be able to launch multiple instances of a couple of programs to run simultaneously. To do so, I use `execle` to be able to pass some parameters if needed. Here's (roughly) my code :

```
char **my_env;

if(argc == 10){
    my_env[0] = malloc(20+sizeof(argv[9]));
    my_env[1] = NULL;
    snprintf(my_env[0], 20+sizeof(*argv[9]), "PREFIXE=%s", argv[9]);
}else{
    my_env[0] = NULL;
}

for(i=1; i <= n; i++){
    if((pid=fork()) == 0){
        execle(first_program, first_program, some_args, ..., (char *) 0, my_env);
        perror("Error at first_program's launch");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        if((pid = fork()) == 0){
            execl(second_program, second_program, some_args, ..., (char *) NULL, my_env);
            perror("Error at second_program's launch");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

execle(third_program, third_program, some_args, ..., (char *) NULL, my_env);
perror("Error at third_program's launch");
exit(1);
```

My problem is when `n` is greater than 1, the execle for second_program and third_program returns a bad adress weither `my_env` is `NULL` or not.

When I replaced them by `execl`, everything works fine.

Comment: The `...` in your code would cause a compiler error. Thus you are not showing us the actual code you are using. Perhaps the error is your real code, not the one you posted here.

Comment: I obviously don't have those in my actual code. otherwise, even the execl wouldn't work.

Comment: The problem is in the way you're setting up `my_env`.  You need `char *my_env[2];` so that you've got some pointers.

Comment: `my_env` is not initialized, you should do something like `my_env = malloc(2 * sizeof *my_env);`. Also `sizeof(argv[9])` is the size of a pointer, not the string.

Comment: @nos Sorry, I was angered to see my post getting downvoted so quickly and didn't properly read your comment.


Anyway, Mecki, Jonathan Leffler and mch were right. After initializing my_env with :

`char **my_env = {NULL, NULL};`

The program worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize memory for `my_env`. You tell the compiler

```
char **my_env;
```

that means `my_env` is a pointer `*` to an array of `char *` pointers. Okay... but directly after that declaration, `my_env` has a random value, so it is a pointer to random memory. Where is that array it points to? You have not yet created such an array, you just declared a pointer to one.

You then just use `my_env`, either like this

```
my_env[0] = ...;
```

This means "write the value ... to the first entry of the array `my_env` points to"... again, what array? Your `my_env` doesn't point to any array!

Either you must provide static memory for `my_env`:

```
char * my_env[2] = { NULL, NULL };
```

or dynamic:

```
char ** my_env = calloc(sizeof(char *), 2);
// ... and when you are done with it ...
free(my_env);
```

Comment: For an array of 2 pointers, there's no point in the dynamic allocation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please refrain from telling people how they are supposed to write code or what you consider meaningful or not. Both is valid, both is correct, both solves his problem, it's up to him to decide which way to go. You don't know the app, you don't know the real code, you don't know the hardware it is going to run, you know nothing about the whole project and still you dare to judge which solution is best? Go write your own answer, you had your chance to do that and you didn't.